# Ratio Inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, fractions

How can I prove that,

$$\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{n}}{b_{1}+b_{2}+\dots+b_{n}} \le \max_i\left\{\frac{a_{i}}{b_{i}}\right\}$$

where $1 \le i \le n$, and $a_{i} \neq a_{j}$ and $b_{i} \neq b_{j}, \forall i \neq j$

**Edit**
I have figured out that the above assumptions about $a_{i}$, and $b_{i}$ are not needed.

Comment: Tried induction? Hint case $n=2$ should be enough to do the lot.

Comment: Should we need $b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n\neq 0$ and each $b_i\neq 0$?

Comment: @Solumilkyu very much. We need $b_i\neq 0$, though the other conditions on $a_i, b_i$ mentioned are actually not needed.

Comment: could you please give reference of this inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose this holds for $n=2$ (prove this base case yourself). Then 
$$\frac{(a_1+...a_k)+a_{k+1}}{(b_1+...+b_k)+b_{k+1}}\le \max\left(\frac{a_1+...+a_k}{b_1+...+b_{k}}, \frac{a_{k+1}}{b_{k+1}}\right)$$

Comment: thanks for the hint...I am still trying to prove it for the base case....doesn't seem so straight forward to me. Any further hints?

Comment: The base case is quite straightforward, if you post your attempt, I am sure you'll get responses guiding you better.

Comment: thanks. I was able to prove the base case. I am not sure what to do next. Looking at your inequality above, I doubt that this is what I want, because the right hand side is not exactly the maximum ratio among all. You are writing it as the maximum between 2 ratios only. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The next step would be to use the induction hypothesis and you will be done.

Comment: so because the first argument in the max term above is less than or equal to the max of the ratios separated (without the sum) by the inductive hypothesis, it must be true that we can replace the max term by the max over all ratios. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. More precisely replacing extends the inequality chain with another $\le \max(\max_{i\le k}(a_i/b_i), a_{k+1}/b_{k+1})=\max_{i\le k+1}(a_i/b_i)$

Answer (score 3):

The $a_i$ can be arbitrary real numbers, but the $b_i$ need to
be *positive*. Then
$$ \tag{*}
  a_j \le b_j \cdot \left\{ \max_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} \right \}
  \quad \text{for $j =1, \ldots, n$}
$$
and adding these gives the desired inequality.

If the $b_i$ are not required to be positive then the
inequality must not hold, a 
counter-example is
$$
   \frac {2 - 1}{3 - 2} > \max \left\{ \frac{2}{3}, \frac{-1}{-2}  \right \} \, .
$$

Comment: thanks. In my case, all numbers are positive or 0. I am ignoring the 0 case for now, and assuming they are all positive.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: $b_i = 0$ would make a fraction $a_i/b_i$ undefined. But with $b_i > 0$ the above proof works.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I am not sure I can see a proof yet. It seems very high level to me.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: Just let me know which part is unclear. Can you see that $(*)$ holds for $j =1, ..., n$?

Comment: What you wrote is clear. Though, I had to play a bit with the inequality to show that it holds. Thank you.